# 3 monitor set up on Lenovo Ideapad 3 is okay long term or not?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I just connected a USB monitor and HDMI monitor to my Lenovo and right away get a 3 screen setup on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

https://www.amazon.ca/AOC-I1659FWUX-15-6-Screen-14700510/dp/B06X9C6XFK

The USB monitor I know uses quite a bit of CPU and my other HDMI is like a 26 inch LG gaming monitor.

Is this bad for my Lenovo Ideapad 3 long term?
I have a cooling pad but what should I be looking out for in terms of not overburdening the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your concerns are, but I believe they are largely unfounded and should not pose any long term issues.  Some comments which speak to your statements and may be helpful -

- The physical size of the screen is irrelevant to the amount of processing, this all depends on the amount of pixels.
- The amount of CPU required to run the screen will depend heavily on what you are doing with it. Playing games or running videos will tax the CPU a lot more heavily then writing a spreadsheet.
- Laptops (indeed all modern laptop/desktop CPU's I'm aware of) have protections in place to prevent damage to the CPU from overheating.  It might shorten the life of the CPU, but I put to you if it shortens it from 20 years to 19.5 years, its unlikely to be a concern, the CPU will outlive the useful life of the computer.
- Were I to be concerned about something I might be concerned about the power draw of the monitor being fed from USB3.  Again, it should be fine, but it does mean you are forcing the power brick to work harder and more power to run through parts of the circuit.   If this does reduce the life of the laptop it would likely be stress on the power supply, which can likely be replaced.  That said, per https://us.aoc.com/en-US/products/monitor/i1659fwux/specification it uses a paltry 8 watts, so I would not worry about it.